# Eager loading accessible_by scope in CanCanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading, cancancan

So I am using rails together with  CanCanCan.
I have users which have access to 0 or more Projects
Each Project has on or more Subprojects.
Both projects and subprojects have managers
If you are a manager of a project, you can see all its subprojects
If you are a manager of a subproject, you can also see the project (but not necesarrily any other subprojects within that project)

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :sub_projects
      has_many :ordered_sub_projects, ->() { order('name') }
      has_many :project_managers
end

class ProjectManagers < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :sub_project
end

class Subproject < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :project
      has_many :subproject_managers
end

class SubProjectManagers < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :sub_project
end

class Ability
      def initialize(user)
          can? :read, Project, { managers: user.id }
          can? :read, Project, { sub_projects: { subproject_managers: user.id } } # To allow to see projects if you are manager of subproject

          can? :read, SubProject, { subproject_managers: user.id } 
          can? :read, SubProject, { project: { project_managers: user.id } }
      end
end
```

Now I want to display all projects for a given user which I can do with:

```
Projects.all.accessible_by(ability)
```

But on my overview page I also want to add quicklinks to all (allowed) subprojects (using bootstrap dropdown).
Originally I used the equivalent of the following in my view code:

```
Projects.all.accessible_by(ability).order(:name).each do |project|
   project.sub_projects.accessible_by(ability).order(:name).each do |sub|
     add_link sub.name, sub
   end
end
```

But this caused a huge N+1 problem when displaying many projects. [1]
So now I changed to.

```
Projects.all.accessible_by(ability).
             preload(:ordered_subprojects).order(:name).each do |project|
       project.ordered_subprojects.each do |sub|
         add_link sub.name, sub if can?(:read, sub)
       end
end
```

which is a lot faster but less clean.Also I suspect the can? method is relatively slow as well in this case.

Ideally it would be possible to eagerload the associated has_many with the correct accessible_by loaded. Unfortunatly I don't see a method to do so

[1] In fact it was even worse, because each subproject also had Teams in them which similar access semantas as SubProject (each team had one or more maangers, if you can see the team you can see the SubProject, and the Project). Quicklinks to Teams are also added on the projects index page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use technique similar to what eager loading does inside - fetch all accessible subprojects at once and then group them by `project_id`.

Like so:

```
subprojects_hash = Subproject.accessible_by(ability).group_by(&:project_id)
Projects.all.accessible_by(ability).each do |project|
  # do smth with project
  if subprojects_hash[project.id]
    # and subprojects...
  end
end
```